# Not able to retrieve values of the collapsable tree using jQuery plugin in the polymer 2.0

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, polymer, polymer-2.x

I'm a beginner in Javascript and jQuery and I am trying to create a custom element of collapsable tree using the [jQuery plugin ztree](http://www.treejs.cn/v3/demo.php#_101) in the Polymer 2.0. For the parent and the nodes of the tree, I gave the values in the array as shown in the **tree-element.html** below.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<link rel="import" href="./bower_components/polymer/polymer-element.html">
<script type="text/javascript" src="./js/jquery-1.4.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./js/jquery.ztree.core.js"></script>


<dom-module id="tree-element">
  <template>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/zTreeStyle/zTreeStyle.css" type="text/css">
          <div>
              <ul id="treeDemo" class="ztree" style="overflow-y: auto;">[[data]]</ul>
          </div>
  </template>

  <script>
    /**
     * `tree-element`
     * tree element
     *
     * @customElement
     * @polymer
     * @demo demo/index.html
     */
    class TreeElement extends Polymer.Element {

      static get is() { return 'tree-element'; }
      static get properties() {
        return {
          settings: {
                    type: Object,
                    value: {}       
                },
          data: 
          {
            type: Array,
            value: [
   {name:"test1", open:true, children:[
      {name:"test1_1"}, {name:"test1_2"}]},
   {name:"test2", open:true, children:[
      {name:"test2_1"}, {name:"test2_2"}]}
   ]     
          }
        };
      }

      ready() 
      {
          super.ready();
          $.fn.zTree.init($("#treeDemo"), this.settings, this.data);
      }
    }    
    window.customElements.define(TreeElement.is, TreeElement);
  </script>
</dom-module>
</html>
```

Along with that, this is my **index.html** file code.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=1, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=yes">

    <title>tree-element demo</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery-1.4.4.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery.ztree.core.js"></script>
    <script src="../bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.js"></script>

    <link rel="import" href="../../iron-demo-helpers/demo-pages-shared-styles.html">
    <link rel="import" href="../../iron-demo-helpers/demo-snippet.html">
    <link rel="import" href="../tree-element.html">

    <custom-style>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/zTreeStyle/zTreeStyle.css" type="text/css">
      <style is="custom-style" include="demo-pages-shared-styles">
      </style>
    </custom-style>
  </head>
  <body> 
      <demo-snippet>
        <template>
          <tree-element></tree-element>
        </template>    
      </demo-snippet>
  </body>
</html>
```

I was hoping to get the tree structure as the output but, the output I am getting by running the command **polymer serve --open** from the project directory is shown in the below image.

[image: Output of the index.html file]

Please suggest how to fix this issue as I'm feeling extremely clueless right now because of my lack of knowledge and experience in this field.

Comment: jQuery plugins don’t work inside of Shadow DOM because typically they try to query for something starting at the document level and the shadow root blocks this. https://medium.com/dev-channel/dont-use-jquery-plugins-with-shadow-dom-e161f1891511   Instead, As I saw you want to make a tree. Try to use dom-repeate and creat your own three, Or If you share me a mock up drawing I will try to write with 'dom-repeat'

Answer (score 0):

Here below a simple tree element that you may develop: tree-element.html

```
<link rel="import" href="bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">
<link rel="import" href="bower_components/iron-icons/iron-icons.html">
<link rel="import" href="bower_components/iron-icon/iron-icon.html">
<link rel="import" href="bower_components/paper-icon-button/paper-icon-button.html">

<dom-module id="tree-element">
  <template>
    <style>
      :host {
        display: block;
        position: relative;
        padding-top: 50px;
        padding-bottom: 64px;
        min-height: 100vh
      }
    paper-icon-button.menuList{
          padding-left: 50px;
    }
    </style>

  <paper-icon-button icon="menu" on-tap="extractList">Test</paper-icon-button> <span>Test2</span>
  <template is="dom-if" if="{{show}}">
    <template is= "dom-repeat" items="{{menuList}}">
      <br/>
      <paper-icon-button class="menuList" icon ="{{item.icon}}"></paper-icon-button><span>{{item.text}} </span> 
    </template>
  </template>
  </template>

  <script>
    class TreeElemen extends Polymer.Element {
      static get is() { return 'tree-element'; }
      static get properties() {
        return {
          show: {
            type: Boolean,
            value: false
          },
          menuList: {
            type:Array,
            value() {return [{"icon":"android", "text":"Android"},
  {"icon":"bug-report", "text":"Bug report"}]}
}}}
extractList() {
this.show=!this.show;         
}}
window.customElements.define(TreeElemen.is, TreeElemen);
  </script>
</dom-module>
```

Comment: I'll try this code and will let you know about the output but meanwhile please tell me if I should add anything in the index.html file except the <tree-element></tree-element> in the body tag.

Comment: Just only `<script src="bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-loader.js"></script> ` if you use another browsers then Chrome.

Comment: The icons "android" and "bugreport" are not displayed. Moreover, what we have to do for creating a different node (parent) of the tree.

Comment: Be sure to install and with bower and import `iron-icons.html` and `iron-icon.html` or you may use your own icon with `src="images/someImage.png"`. So, it should work. Because I tested. If you want to add more sub-tree, put into dom-repeat with wrapped dom-if (shown as above), you can make more complex and more detailed. Also you can add more rows with adding menuList Array property.